# After replacing html code as text, the text converts to html and gets executed, how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, xss

on the page you can create new blogs and in the editor you can insert for example

```
<p>MyWord <img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>
```

and if you publish that, the you will see this whole string as text on the blog page. But if I now replace 'MyWord' with something else, the html string gets executed.
To replace the word I use

```
function replaceWords(words) {
  const container = $('body :not(script):not(.myClass)');

  for (const key of Object.keys(words)) {
    container
      .contents()
      .filter((_, i) => {
        if (i.nodeType === 3 && i.nodeValue.match(words[key].reg)) {
          return i.nodeType === 3 && i.nodeValue.match(words[key].reg);
        }
      })
      .replaceWith(function () {
        return this.nodeValue.replace(words[key].reg, createWordTag(words[key]));
      });
  }
}
```

So I suspect that the editor block the html string from executing, but after I replace the word, the string is inserted back into the DOM as html code. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic. How come the script is executed when the script tag does not exist?

Comment: You should use `.each()` instead of `.map()` if you're not using the return value.

Comment: @bam For example you create a new article and you write your text inside the editor on the webpage and inside your text you have '<p>MyWord <img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>', after you save the article then you see exactly the string '<p>MyWord <img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>' as a text. But if you run the above script and replace MyWord with something else, then '<p><img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>' disappears only the replaced word remains and the alert is executed, This happens only if p is around the word and the img inside p. When replacing the DOM node, the html

Comment: string gets converted from text to actual html code, so that '<p>MyWord <img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>' is not more a text string. Only the replaced word is a text string and ''<p><img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>' is actual html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.replaceWith()` method treats the replacement content as HTML to be rendered if it's a string, not as plain text.

Instead of replacing the element, just assign to the text node's `nodeValue`.

It would also be better if you just looped over the DOM elements once, and then performed all the text replacements in that.

```
function replaceStr(myStrArr) {
  const container = $('body :not(script)');
  container
    .contents()
    .each((_, el) => {
      if (el.nodeType == 3) {
        el.nodeValue = myStrArr.reduce(({
          reg,
          newStr
        }, text) => text.replace(reg, newStr), el.nodeValue);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for the answer. But what if I want to wrap a <span> around the replaced word to change the color of the word. How would I do it then? For example I want to replace 'MyWord' with '<span class='red' id='newID'>NewWord'</span>' So that I can highlight the replaced words.

Comment: Don't replace the text node, replace the container's HTML. When you extract the container's HTML, the literal `<` and `>` will be converted to entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Thank you again Barmar, but it's to complicated for. I added my first post, with the 1:1 function I'm using. Can you please have a look again. So I'm excluding from the container '$('body :not(script):not(.myClass)');' script and .myClass, because I don't want to replace anything inside < > like the class name and I also don't want to replace a word which was already replaced. For example if you look for 'word' and 'wordnext', then if I wouldn't exclude myClass then it would replace 'word' inside 'wordnext'. Then it would be <span>word<span>next</span></span> it should be <span>wordnext</spa

Comment: Sorry it's complicated, at least for me and it took some time to figure this things out. If I use your solution, then '<p> <img src=x onerror=alert(something)></p>' doesn't convert to html. That's great. But how exactly do I let my span be html code? Didn't understand you last comment.

Comment: `$(element).html(function(_, oldHTML) { return oldHTML.replace(reg, newStr); })`

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar, but it's not working. So it's replacing the words, but it's ignoring the ':not(script):not(.myClass)'. So that I end up with example <span><span>word</span>next</span>. Damn didn't thought it's so complicated to replace some text with html code.

Comment: Try `:not(:has(*))` to only match leaf elements. Otherwise you're matching at every level of the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: No nothing can be excluded ':not(:has(*)):not(script):not(textarea):not(textarea *):not(a *):not(a)' for example I don't want to replace words inside <a> </a> or other custom classes. It's very important to be able to exclude stuff, because you don't want to replace everywhere.

Comment: If you want to do this right, I don't think string replacements is the proper method. If you want to replace a text node with other DOM elements, you need to create the elements explicitly. When you do the string replace, there's no way for the browser to know which tags are literal and which should be rendered as HTML.

Comment: I don't think this is an easy task, and I'm not going to try to solve it here.

Comment: No problem Barmar, it works now almost as it should. I'm new to the stuff. You helped me a lot. Thank you.